# Escapying hyphen in Capistrano Variable

Tags: deployment, capistrano

Im my Capistrano deployment setting file I have to grab a domain in variable. Problem is that the domain contains hyphen :

```
set :production_domain, 'www.my-domain.com'
```

I was woundering if I can escape hyphen in the variable?

Thanks

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This should do the trick:

```
set :'production-domain', 'www.my-domain.com'
```

Then:

```
fetch(:'production-domain')
```